# Push notification in Cordova 2.9.0 for IOS Example or sample code

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting issue to implement Push notification in phone gap (version Cordova 2.9.0) for IOS .Please share the sample code or example links with tutorial based so that I can implemented easily.

I have created the certificate regarding this which is working fine. But I could not know how to implement code in Cordova 2.9.0 using plugins. please help me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

As far as I know PhoneGap and Cordova are related.So you can check this tutorial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you ... It is not useful link for me I used this one already.